# setting javascript variable to certain object attributes

Tags: javascript

I have a fairly basic javascript question that I can't seem to figure out. Lets say I have a data object like this:

```
var data = [
{
        key: 1,
        attr2: "2",
        attr3: "3",
        attr4: "4",
        attr5: "5"  
};
{
        key: 2,
        attr2: "10",
        attr3: "3a",
        attr4: "ad",
        attr5: "5asdf"  
};
{
        key: 3,
        attr2: "a",
        attr3: "b",
        attr4: "c",
        attr5: "d"  
};
```

and I want to create another object with just attr1 and attr2, do I do it like this?

```
var data2 = data[attr1, attr2]
```

tried it this way but I get `attr1 is undefined`.

Comment: `data2 = [ data[1], data[2] ]`

Comment: Do you want to copy the attr1 and attr2 values from data to data2?

Comment: Your object is invalid because of the semi-colons. Also, what is `attr1`?

Comment: @torazaburo And things like `5asdf`.

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript. `5asdf` is neither a string, nor a valid idenifier.

Comment: where is `attr1` property for inner object?

Comment: I suspect you want `data.map(({attr1, attr2}) => ({attr1, attr2}))`.

Comment: I don't know how people are answering. This question doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an array with the keys and map the new objects with the wanted keys.

While you have no key `attr1`, you get undefined.

```js
var data = [{ key: 1, attr2: 2, attr3: 3, attr4: 4, attr5: 5 }, { key: 2, attr2: 10, attr3: '3a', attr4: 'ad', attr5: '5asdf' }, { key: 3, attr2: 'a', attr3: 'b', attr4: 'c', attr5: 'd' }],
    keys = ['attr1', 'attr2'],
    result = data.map(function (a) {
        var o = {};
        keys.forEach(function (k) {
            o[k] = a[k];
        });
        return o;
    });

console.log(result);
```

Bonus: Short version in ES6 with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```js
var data = [{ key: 1, attr2: 2, attr3: 3, attr4: 4, attr5: 5 }, { key: 2, attr2: 10, attr3: '3a', attr4: 'ad', attr5: '5asdf' }, { key: 3, attr2: 'a', attr3: 'b', attr4: 'c', attr5: 'd' }],
    keys = ['attr1', 'attr2'],
    result = data.map(o => keys.reduce((r, k) => Object.assign(r, { [k]: o[k] }), {}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: The question is unclear. The OP already said `tried it this way but I get attr1 is undefined.` may be he is not expecting `undefined`

Comment: *attr1 is undefined.* yes, because `attr1` is not defined in the code. it looks like a variable, but without content.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to generate new array using `data` array elements.

```
var res = data.map(function(o) {
  return {
    attr1: o.attr1,
    attr2: o.attr2
  }
})
```

```js
var data = [{
  key: 1,
  attr2: 2,
  attr3: 3,
  attr4: 4,
  attr5: 5
}, {
  key: 2,
  attr2: 10,
  attr3: '3a',
  attr4: 'ad',
  attr5: '5asdf'
}, {
  key: 3,
  attr2: 'a',
  attr3: 'b',
  attr4: 'c',
  attr5: 'd'
}];

var res = data.map(function(o) {
  return {
    attr1: o.attr1,
    attr2: o.attr2
  }
})

console.log(res);
```

---

**UPDATE 1 :** With ES6 [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```
var res = data.map(({attr1, attr2}) => ({attr1, attr2}))
```

```js
var data = [{
  key: 1,
  attr2: 2,
  attr3: 3,
  attr4: 4,
  attr5: 5
}, {
  key: 2,
  attr2: 10,
  attr3: '3a',
  attr4: 'ad',
  attr5: '5asdf'
}, {
  key: 3,
  attr2: 'a',
  attr3: 'b',
  attr4: 'c',
  attr5: 'd'
}];

var res = data.map(({attr1, attr2}) => ({attr1, attr2}))

console.log(res);
```

---

**UPDATE 2 :** If you want to get multiple properties from an object and keys are stored in an array then use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method for generating the object.

```
var res = data.map(function(obj) {
  return keysArray.reduce(function(o, k) { // generate object
    o[k] = obj[k]; // define the property
    return o; // return object reference
  }, {}); // set iinitial value as empty object
});
```

```js
var data = [{
    key: 1,
    attr2: 2,
    attr3: 3,
    attr4: 4,
    attr5: 5
  }, {
    key: 2,
    attr2: 10,
    attr3: '3a',
    attr4: 'ad',
    attr5: '5asdf'
  }, {
    key: 3,
    attr2: 'a',
    attr3: 'b',
    attr4: 'c',
    attr5: 'd'
  }],
  keys = ['attr1', 'attr2'];

var res = data.map(function(obj) {
  return keys.reduce(function(o, k) {
    o[k] = obj[k];
    return o;
  }, {});
});

console.log(res);
```